# I am trying to parse an array of string in Jade but always results in 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

I have been trying to parse an array of strings on my jade file but it doesn't seem to work. 
I can console log the array of strings from my mongodb collection but it does not reflect on my jade.

**my code: from js**

```
(global variable) let secretstitle = [];

 dbo.collection("users1").findOne({secretdocument:"rousbepistola"} ,function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        ssn.secretpost = data.secretpost;
        ssn.secrettitle = data.title;
        console.log(data.secretpost);
        console.log(data.title)
        console.log(ssn.secretpost[0]);
        console.log(data.title[0])


        for(let i = 0; i < (data.secretpost).length; i++) {
          secretstitle.push(data.secretpost[i])
        }
        console.log(secretstitle);
        console.log('Yay!')

        db.close();
```

**my code: from jade**

```
    .row
      each n in secretstitle;
        .jumbotron.col-md-12
          h1 #{n}
          | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
          h6 January 24, 2019  08:54:05  @username
          | &#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
          p
            | W3Schools is optimized for learning
```

I am trying to create a blog type content that adds to itself indefinitely like Facebook, 9gag, or twitter. I have received the console.log("yay") on my terminal. I appreciate every help I could get. By the way, my collection looks like this:

```
id:ObjectId("random")
secretposts:Array
   0:"post1"
   1:"post 2"
   3:"post 3"
title:Array
   0:"title 1"
   1:"Title 2"
   3:"Title 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the callback from your mongodb findOne call you need to add a `res.render`:

```
dbo.collection("users1").findOne({secretdocument:"rousbepistola"} ,function(err, data){

  res.render('viewname', data);

});
```

Without that the pug/jade engine won't call the template with the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

was just able to solve it now with my jade code as follow

```
   .row
      - for (var i = 0; i < himitsupost.length; ++i) {
        return
      .jumbotron.col-md-12(style='background-color:lightgreen;')
        h3 #{himitsutitle[i]}
        h5 #{himitsupost[i]}
      - }
```

And my js file as follows

```
 dbo.collection("users1").findOne({secretdocument:"rousbepistola"} ,function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err;
    ssn.secretpost = data.secretpost;
    ssn.secrettitle = data.title;
    console.log(data.secretpost);
    console.log(data.title)
    // console.log(ssn.secretpost[0]);
    // console.log(data.title[0])

    secretspost = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < (data.secretpost).length; i++) {
      secretspost.push(data.secretpost[i])
    }

    secretstitle = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < (data.title).length; i++) {
      secretstitle.push(data.title[i])
    }


    console.log(secretspost);
    console.log('Yay!')

    db.close();

});
});
  res.render('release',{username:ssn.username, himitsutitle:secretstitle, himitsupost:secretspost});
```